# logged subprocess.communicate()?

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

I have to call a script from Python and collect its output. So,

```
p = subprocess.Popen ("script", shell = False, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
out_lines = p.communicate ("\n".join (in_lines)) [0]
```

... except I want to log every `out_line` as it comes in case, you know, the worst happens (either in the subprocess or in the main process).

I have

1. no control over `script`
2. no desire to copy & patch the source code of `communicate()` in my Python
3. no guarantee that the script returns an output line for each input line.
4. better avoid calling the platform-dependent tee utility.

Except for these four workable, but inconvenient solutions, is there anything else that I'm overlooking? Something like replacing `stdout = PIPE` with a logging wrapper perhaps?

Thank you. I'll be here all week.

Comment: Is monkey patching included in number 2? What about wrapping stdout?

Comment: As long as it doesn't involve copying [much] code from the original communicate() source code, I guess I'd consider it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've essentially got two threads of control which overlap.

1. Send input to the subprocess.
2. Read data from subprocess as it become available.

Doing this in a platform independent way doesn't give you too many options apart from using threading (or perhaps a select loop).

Your code in question only appears to be interested in stdout so you could just invoke a thread which reads stdout and writes the contents to a file.

Here's an example:

```
import subprocess
import os
import threading


class LogThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread which will read from `pipefd` and write all contents to
    `fileobj` until `pipefd` is closed.  Used as a context manager, this thread
    will be automatically started, and joined on exit, usually when the
    child process exits.
    """
    def __init__(self, pipefd, fileobj):
        self.pipefd = pipefd
        self.fileobj = fileobj
        super(LogThread, self).__init__()
        self.setDaemon(1)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            line = self.pipefd.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            self.fileobj.write(line)
            self.fileobj.flush()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.join()


# Here's how to use the LogThread.    
p = subprocess.Popen ("script", shell = False, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
with open('logfile.txt', 'wt') as logfile:
    with LogThread(p.stdout, logfile):
        p.stdin.write("\n".join(in_lines))
        p.stdin.close()
```

This probably duplicates small parts of `Popen.communicate()` but it's not a lot of code and is platform agnostic.

**A note about buffering:**
It is normal for stdout to be buffered to non-tty devices, eg pipes.  Usually, stderr is not buffered.  You typically have no control over whether the application being run buffers its output.  At best you can guess how it might determine whether to use buffering, with most applications calling `isatty()` to determine whether it should buffer.  So, setting buffering 0 on the log file may not be the correct solution to avoid buffering.  If buffering is 0, each character of output is written as a single `write()` call and very inefficient.  The above solution has been modified to perform line buffering.

The following link might be useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: What is MyPopen here?

Comment: @dan3 MyPopen was a typo, fixed to subprocess.Popen.  I originally wrote a Popen subclass to handle a communicate with log file but decided that the current presentation is cleaner.

Comment: I did this and got caught because the subprocess buffers its stdin (presumably because it detects a non-tty) and the main process never closes p.stdin. You need to close p.stdin -- and also wait on p to be sure it finished its output. Please edit the answer in order to not mislead future readers :)

Comment: You also must have meant self.pipefd.read(1), otherwise the entire subprocess output is read into memory (and the while loop in LogThread would be useless); the logfile should also be opened either unbuffered or line-buffered, because "the worst" can happen in both the main- or the sub-process.

Comment: @dan3 The code given was a guide only, more proof of concept.  Nevertheless, I've updated the example with line buffering added.  Closing stdin is up to you if that's what your program expects, I've added it to the example.  See the additional note about buffering, it's something that is application specific and will depend on your application as to what is appropriate.  eg You may need to run your application using something like `unbuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

The actions of `subprocess.communicate` rely on platform detection. On Windows, the work is done using threads, and simply using a file wrapper suffices for logging purposes.

On Unix, however, `subprocess` uses `select`, which relies on obtaining the file descriptor (`file.fileno()`), so this technique does not work. It would be possible to just create another pipe and duplicate the output in python, but it's a bit more involved, and since you're writing platform dependent code anyway, on Unix you generally can use the [`tee`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) command for that exact purpose.

Knowing this, here's a platform dependent example that fulfills your requirements:

```
import subprocess
import sys

class FileWrapperWithLog(object):
    def __init__(self, file_object, filename):
        self.f= file_object
        self.log= open(filename, 'wb')
    def read(self):
        data= self.f.read()
        self.log.write(data)
        return data
    def close(self):
        return self.f.close()

FILENAME="my_file.log"
if sys.platform == "win32":
    p= subprocess.Popen('dir', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.stdout= FileWrapperWithLog( p.stdout, FILENAME )
else:
    p= subprocess.Popen('ls | tee '+FILENAME, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

Another option would be monkey patching `subprocess`, but it would be an error prone process, as communicate is a complex method, and has the previously mentioned platform-dependent behaviour.

Comment: OK, this is an option, unfortunately platform- and status-quo-dependent. At first look it looks impossible to intercept select() and fileno()

Comment: @dan3 it's not impossible to intercept `select` or `fileno` - the problem is what you'll substitute them with. You'll end up reimplementing `tee` in python (see answer edit)

Comment: I'm starting to lean towards a "clean" tee in Python and establishing the pipeline with subprocess. Platform agnostic and no patching of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

The following simple script illustrates an approach which can be used (cross-platform):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys
import threading

def handle_line(line):
    print(line) # or log it, or whatever

def reader(stream):
    while True:
        s = stream.readline()
        if not s:
            break
        handle_line(s)
    stream.close()

p = Popen(sys.argv[1].split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
# Get threads  ready to read the subprocess output
out_reader = threading.Thread(target=reader, args=(p.stdout,))
err_reader = threading.Thread(target=reader, args=(p.stderr,))
out_reader.start()
err_reader.start()
# Provide the subprocess input
p.stdin.write("Hello, world!")
p.stdin.close()
# Wait for the child process to complete
p.wait()
# And for all its output to be consumed
out_reader.join()
err_reader.join()
print('Done.')
```

When run with a program that echoes its `stdin`, such as `cat` (or, on Windows, Gnu-Win32 `cat.exe`), you should get:

```
Hello, world!
Done.
```

as the output. This should work with larger output - I use this technique in [`python-gnupg`](http://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/), where I need to process lines (from `stderr`) as they come in, rather than all at the end (which is why I couldn't use `communicate`).

**Update:** There are lots of ways the "OOP niceties" could be structured - I don't especially find Austin Phillips' version that useful for me. However, I've shown the steps that need to be taken in the simplest manner, and that can be built on top of, according to one's individual needs.

Comment: This is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/users/302243/austin-phillips answer, without the OOP niceties but with stderr handling. I think using Popen but ditching communicate() with all its cross-platform and std* combo optimizations is the cleanest approach. Upvoted, but I'll go with the earlier answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the p.stdin.close() and p.wait() were very important, and I missed them at a casual reading. The accepted answer will need to be edited (I still prefer the OOP niceties, particularly if the logging needs to be done multiple times for multiple streams)